# How to create node.js project to standalone exe file for windows.

Tags: node.js, windows, websocket, exe, electron

I have built an application in Node js which uses Websockets for communicating events to browser. I want to bundle that application into one .exe file so that it can run on client machine without Node being installed.

I googled few approaches and finally used Nexe for bundling.
All goes fine but when I am running the output file it is giving issue with Websocket module.

```
TypeError: WebSocketServer is not a function
at Array.__dirname.call.C:\Users\Raghav Tandon\WinPos\BrowserIntegrat
ion\js\RestImpl.js.http (nexe.js:15287:12)
at initModule (nexe.js:29:11)
at nexe.js:31:64
at Array.__dirname.call.C:\Users\Raghav Tandon\WinPos\BrowserIntegrat
ion\js\RestWS.js../RestImpl (nexe.js:48:20)
at initModule (nexe.js:29:11)
at Array.forEach (native)
at nexe.js:39:8
at nexe.js:46:4
at NativeModule.compile (node.js:945:5)
at Function.NativeModule.require (node.js:893:18)
```

> Can electron will work?
>
> Please, help me on how do I bundle the Node application to an .exe file.

Please share the best practices to do this. TIA

Answer (score 0):

According to [nexe](https://jaredallard.me/nexe/) docs:

> Doesn't support native modules

[nexe](https://jaredallard.me/nexe/) is not yet supported native modules. So, your case would not work because which uses natvie modules.

Alternatively, if you don't care paying costs, [enclosejs](http://enclosejs.com/) would be help you.